Play the Weezer lick
Your task is: Using features of your language of choice, play the Weezer lick (in whatever form).
Inforamtion:
The Weezer lick is a fragment of the song "Buddy Holly" by Weezer.
(here)

Playing the MP3 file is allowed (i.e. Python's playsound.)

Manipulating anything (aka opening new scripts, windows etc.) is disallowed.

Different octaves can be used.


Example:
A5-F5-A5-B5-C6#-B5-A5-F5-E5.
Use whatever you can.
The note frequencies are provided here.

Welcome to CGCC. Adding a link as source is fine, but all challenges should be self-provided, in case the link dies a few years from now when someone revisits the challenge. So please explain in the challenge description what a Weezer lick is and perhaps give an example (can be in pseudo-code) of what to play. I've also added the [music] and [audio] tags.

Hi there hello, welcome to the code golf stack exchange. As it stands, this question requires some more information to make it suitable for the site: it is unclear what exactly counts as playing the weezer lick. Does playing a MP3/wav/etc file count? Does opening a YouTube video in a new tab count? Or does it need to be a certain sequence of notes played through a library that can play individual musical notes? Also, please specify the exact series of notes that constitutes the weezer lick, and if different octaves can be used.

Potential duplicate

QBASIC, 19 bytes: PLAY "AFAB>C#<BAFE"

PowerShell Scripting Language, 217 bytes
[Console]::Beep(440,100);Console]::Beep(349,100);Console]::Beep(440,100);Console]::Beep(494,100);Console]::Beep(554,100);Console]::Beep(494,100);Console]::Beep(440,100);Console]::Beep(349,100);[Console]::Beep(329,999)

Plays the Weezer lick (an octave lower)

The code you show above is 217 characters rather than 139.
